# the filter method updates wrongly in react arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, react-hooks

I'm writing a todo list app and I want to filter the tasks by the isDone key which shows whether the user has done the task or not and my code works till here but when my filter returns the completed tasks and you add another task it will be shown in the list although it is not done here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import Select from "react-select";

function TodoForm() {
    const [Inputstate,setState]=useState("");
    const [SelectValue,setSelect]=useState("");
    const [filterTodo,setFilter] = useState([]);
    const [initilState,setInitial]=useState([]);
    const SelectOptions=[
        {value:"",label:"All"},
        {value:"NotDone",label:"Not Completed"},
        {value:"Done",label:"Completed"}
    ];
    const reducer=(state,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "InputChange":
            action.event.preventDefault();
            const value={title:Inputstate,isDone:false,isEditing:false};
            const clone=[...state];
            clone.push(value);
            setInitial(clone);
            setState("");
            return clone;
        case "CompleteTask":
                const TaskClone=[...state];
                const TaskNum={...state[action.id]};
                const TaskResult=TaskNum.isDone?false:true;
                TaskClone[action.id].isDone=TaskResult;
                return TaskClone;
        case "deleteTask":
                const clone2=[...state];
                clone2.splice(action.id,1);
                return clone2;
        case "editTask":
                const editClone=[...state];
                const editNum={...state[action.id]};
                const editResult=editNum.isEditing?false:true;
                editClone[action.id].isEditing=editResult;
                return editClone;
        case "editInput":
            const inputClone=[...state];
            const inputNum={...state[action.id]};
            inputNum.title=action.event.target.value;
            inputClone[action.id]=inputNum;
            return inputClone;
        case "select":
            if(action.event.value===""){
                return initilState;
            }else{
                return filterTodo;
            }
        default:
        return state;
    }
    }
    const [tasks,setTasks]=useReducer(reducer,initilState);
    const SelectChange=((event)=>{
    if(event.value==="NotDone"){
        const NotOption=tasks.filter((item)=>!item.isDone);
        setFilter(NotOption);
    }else if(event.value==="Done"){
        const NotResult=tasks.filter((item)=>item.isDone);
        setFilter(NotResult);
    }
        setTasks({type:"select",event});
        setSelect(event);
    });

    const Uncompleted=tasks.filter((item)=>!item.isDone);
    return (
    <div id={styles.tasks}>
    <header>
        {Uncompleted.length>0&&<h2>Uncompleted Tasks{Uncompleted.length}</h2>}
        <Select
            options={SelectOptions}
            value={SelectValue}
            onChange={SelectChange}
        />
    </header>
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>(setTasks({type:"InputChange",event:e}))}>
        <input type="text" value={Inputstate} 
        onChange={(e)=>setState(e.target.value)}/>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
        <section>
        <ul>
        {tasks.map((task,index)=>{
         if(task.title){
            return <li key={index}>
            {task.isEditing?<input type="text" className={styles.editInput} onChange={(e)=>setTasks({type:"editInput",id:index,event:e})} placeholder="Edited Task" value={task.title}/>
            :<span className={`${task.isDone&&styles.true}`}>Task Name: {task.title}</span>}
            <span><span>Is Task Completed:</span> <input type="checkbox" 
            checked={task.isDone} onClick={()=>setTasks({type:"CompleteTask",id:index,name:task.title})}
            />
            </span>
            <button onClick={()=>setTasks({type:"deleteTask",id:index})}>delete</button>
            <button onClick={()=>setTasks({type:"editTask",id:index})}>{task.isEditing?"change":"edit"}</button>
            </li>
         }else{return null;}  
        })}
        </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    );
}
export default TodoForm;
```

personally, I think I should use useEffect hook for the initialState to change the value of Filtered tasks regularly but when I use it an error is returned

Comment: can you share your complete code in codesandbox or something ?

Comment: I'm not much of a react programmer but this is the first time I've seen calling useState functions from useReducer, and my brain is having trouble deciding how that works.